# How reset error messages language to english

Tags: flash

After one of the 10'th flash player update thrown exceptions appears  in language of my windows system (polish in my case). Example: 'TypeError: Error #1010: Zapytanie...' Is it possible set language to original English on non English  machine?

Comment: I found a page on Adobe that suggests that you can set the locale at least on linux. Maybe there is a solution for Mac in the same way:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/readme-flash-player-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

A hack: Assuming that you have downloaded FP10 from Adobe's web-site, set your language to 'English' [here](http://www.adobe.com/international/selector/) and download the Flash player. Run a fresh install of the player.

Comment: I load debug exe form http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html. I always using English version of adobe site. I think binaries ere the same for any locale.